# What does this gigantic C mean?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, root-systems

This is an excerpt from the paper *Groupes Reductifs* by Borel and Tits.

[image]

Do you see the big "C" in the second paragraph?  What does this notation mean?  I've never seen it before.

Comment: It is $\supset$ and usually denotes containment.

Comment: @Pedro: I think that the reference is to the symbol near the end of the third line of the *third* paragraph (counting the displayed expression as a paragraph break). Complement, perhaps?

Comment: The big C is Bourbaki's notation for the complement.

Comment: One the silliest things in the whole œuvre! ;-)

Comment: Ah, OK. My bad, @BrianM.Scott =) That should be paragraph three, I think?

Comment: It is the 2nd one: the line after the displayed equation is not indented, so a new paragraph does not start there!

Comment: Probably $\psi-(-\psi)$ would have been less silly than $\psi\cap\complement(-\psi)$? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Bourbaki's *Théorie des ensembles*:

[image]

Comment: Jacques Tits was a close friend of Bourbaki — he is, I think, the only one who is thanked (in a footnote, of course) in the whole series of books.